# How can I make it so that the program won't bind to an already in use port?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-asio

I'm using the code below to open a Boost Asio acceptor. I would expect that when I open a second instance of the program, the new instance wouldn't be able to bind to the already in use port 8080. I'm finding, though, that an exception is never actually thrown. How can I make it so that the program won't bind to an already in use port?

This is running on a Windows 7 machine.

```
boost::shared_ptr<asio_ip::tcp::acceptor> acceptor;

try {
    acceptor.reset(new asio_ip::tcp::acceptor(io_service, asio_ip::tcp::endpoint(asio_ip::tcp::v4(), 8080)));
}
catch (...) {
    acceptor.reset(new asio_ip::tcp::acceptor(io_service, asio_ip::tcp::endpoint(asio_ip::tcp::v4(), 0)));
}
```

Comment: what happens if you explicitly disable [`reuse_address`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/reuse_address.html)?

Comment: Yep! Worked. If you make it an answer and specify how to do that I'll accept it.

Comment: answer has been added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to explicitly disable [`reuse_address`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/reuse_address.html) as I'm not sure if this is enabled by default on Windows platforms. This can be done as follows:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service);
...
boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address option(false);
acceptor.set_option(option);
```

Comment: The [constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/basic_socket_acceptor/overload3.html) overload used in the original code has an optional `reuse_addr` argument that defaults to `true`.